# Invalid time zone indicator '' when deploying Java Spring app to heroku

Tags: java, json, spring, heroku, gson

I am trying to deploy a Java Spring app to Heroku, and it works fine on my local machine. But when I push it to the heroku server it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
```

at this line of code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
PricingSample[] samples = gson.fromJson(string, PricingSample[].class);
```

I'm guessing from what I read there has to be some kind of adapter added but I don't know how to add one that would fit here. Usually when there is an invalid time zone indicator it shows the wrong string it's trying to parse.

---

### **Edit:**

I just noticed that the message that the browser shows gives some more information about the string that is trying to be parsed:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Jun 03 08:40:41 UTC 2018 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). For input string:
>   "2018-06-03 07:00:00"